# IIS 7.5 - which version of .net my application is running under

Tags: iis-7.5

Please confirm if following is the right way to verify version of .net my application is running under

In IIS 7.5
-> Select application site node
-> Basic Settings
-> select Application Pool Settings
-> Verify version

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one way to do it and you can do pretty much the same by opening the Advanced Settings and clicking the elipses (<kbd>...</kbd>) button next to the Application pool.